# Internalisation Symfony, Gedmo Translatable, mising translations for related entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, translation

Im using Gedmo Translatable in my project.
I have Product entity and Inclusion entity.
Relation between them is ManyToMany.

Product Entity

```
namespace Traffic\ShopBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Traffic\ShopBundle\Model\Product as ProductModel;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Traffic\ShopBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="Traffic\ShopBundle\Entity\ProductTranslation")
 * 
 */
class Product extends ProductModel {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * 
     * @var type string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Inclusion")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_inclusion",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="inclusion_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     * 
     * @var type Collection
     */
    protected $inclusions;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *   targetEntity="ProductTranslation",
     *   mappedBy="object",
     *   cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     */
    protected $translations;

.....
}
```

Inclusion Entity

```
namespace Traffic\ShopBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Traffic\ShopBundle\Model\Inclusion as InclusionModel;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Traffic\AdminBundle\Repository\TranslatableRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"sauce" = "Sauce", "topping" = "Topping"})
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 * @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="Traffic\ShopBundle\Entity\InclusionTranslation")
 * 
 * @ORM\Table(name="inclusion")
 */
class Inclusion extends InclusionModel {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * 
     * @var type string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *   targetEntity="InclusionTranslation",
     *   mappedBy="object",
     *   cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     */
    protected $translations;
.......
}
```

In my Repository class I have a method to fetch translated object, but it just translates my Product not Inclusions

```
namespace Traffic\ShopBundle\Repository;

use Traffic\AdminBundle\Repository\TranslatableRepository;
use Traffic\ShopBundle\Entity\Kiosk;

/**
 * Description of FinancialTransactionRepository
 *
 * @author bart
 */
class ProductRepository extends TranslatableRepository {


    public function findAllProductsForKiosk(Kiosk $kiosk, $locale = "es"){

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("p")
            ->leftJoin('p.kiosks', 'k')
            ->leftJoin('p.flavours', 'f')
            ->leftJoin('p.inclusions', "i")
            ->leftJoin('p.type', "t")

            ->where('k.kiosk = :kiosk')
        ;

        $qb->setParameter("kiosk", $kiosk);

        $results = $this->getTranslatedQuery($qb, $locale);

        return $results->execute();
    }


}
```

and getTranslatedQuery

```
/**
 * Returns translated Doctrine query instance
 *
 * @param QueryBuilder $qb     A Doctrine query builder instance
 * @param string       $locale A locale name
 *
 * @return Query
 */
protected function getTranslatedQuery(QueryBuilder $qb, $locale = null)
{
    $locale = null === $locale ? $this->defaultLocale : $locale;

    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    $query->setHint(
        Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER,
        'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker'
    );

    $query->setHint(TranslatableListener::HINT_TRANSLATABLE_LOCALE, $locale);

    return $query;
}
```

Is there a way to fetch all translated objects with one query?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should change hydration mode?

```
    $query->setHydrationMode(TranslationWalker::HYDRATE_OBJECT_TRANSLATION);
    $config = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager()->getConfiguration();
    if ($config->getCustomHydrationMode(TranslationWalker::HYDRATE_OBJECT_TRANSLATION) === null) {
        $config->addCustomHydrationMode(
            TranslationWalker::HYDRATE_OBJECT_TRANSLATION,
            'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Hydrator\\ORM\\ObjectHydrator'
        );
    }
```